# Get the last Select option value from a webbrowser control VB6

Tags: javascript, html, vb6

I need to get the value of the last option, from a  box. "SelCONTACTS"

I have a webbrowser control in **VB6** and i have it source code in a TextBox

```
<select name="SelCONTACTS" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'SelCONTACTS\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlContratos">
    <option selected="selected" value="30393">6-4002582</option>
    <option value="194177">A-70P0096</option>
    <option value="220499">B-7000902</option>
</select>
```

the name SelCONTACTS is a fixed name, it wont change. **VALUES and CONTENTS of LIST ITEMS do change.**

Only thing i can imagine is to search for the string and go a couple spaces back  (but thats an horrible way to do it)

```
</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Does the last option value will be always height value then this can be done using jquery.

Comment: You mean if the size of the last value will have the same number of characters? Then yes, If you mean if its only gonna have 3 options? then No, it can have more options or less.